# How can I interpret this sentence?

Tags: traduction

Somebody from France with who I am chatting said the following to me:

> Je t'avoue que je suis un peu confus (j'ai fait une copie-double)

We were talking about her history test and then afterwards she said this. Can anybody help me understand this sentence?

Comment: If she is a she, she should have written *..que je suis un peu confus**e***, but perhaps that mistake is part of her confusion. Note also that *je suis confus(e)* seems an anglicism here. In French, *je suis confus* is usually a polite way to say "I'm sorry/ashamed/embarrassed".

Comment: Which part do you not understand? You have to be specific about what you need help with. I'll close this question until it's edited to focus on a particular point. The title has to be specific too.

Answer (score 2):

> Je t'avoue que je suis un peu confus

could be translated as "**I admit that I'm a little confused**".

A *copie double* (or *feuille double*, which they're sold [here](https://www.bureau-vallee.fr/cd-cambr-per-a4-f400-70g-seyes-65301.html) as, for example) is just a sheet of A3 paper folded in half, typically used at school in France for answering tests on. Your friend could also have just called it a *copie*, which [Larousse defines as](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/copie/19103?q=copie#18995)

> feuille double de papier, de format standard, destinée à la rédaction

i.e. a double sheet of paper, standard format, for writing.

So

> j'ai fait une copie double

means that she filled a whole one of these "double sheets", presumably with the answers to the test.